# Yesterday and today date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time

My date column in my database is in this format: `date('Y-M-j H:i:s');`.
A am trying to run a query to get all transactions done today and another one for all transactions done yesterday. Please help on best way to do this.

I tried the below but it wasn't working

```
 $yesterday = date("Y-M-j 00:00:01", strtotime("-1 day"));
$yesterday2 = date("Y-M-j 23:59:59", strtotime("-1 day"));

$query_syesterday = "SELECT sum(amount), sum(amtnaira) FROM transactions WHERE transtype = 'buy' AND batch !='' AND date BETWEEN '$yesterday' AND '$yesterday2'";
$syesterday = mysql_query($query_syesterday, $egold1) or die(mysql_error());
$row_syesterday = mysql_fetch_assoc($syesterday);
$totalRows_syesterday = mysql_num_rows($syesterday);
```

Comment: how about NOW() - INTERVAL 1  DAY and NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$query_last_two_days = "SELECT sum(amount), sum(amtnaira) 
   FROM transactions 
      WHERE transtype = 'buy' 
        AND batch !='' 
        AND date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)";
```

You can get the last two days easily like this.  You can change `NOW()` to a date of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$yesterday= date("Y-m-d", time()-86400)." 00:00:00";
$yesterday2= date("Y-m-d", time()-86400)." 23:59:59";
```

Comment: @Nile: `echo` isn't helpful in such cases, `var_dump` is. Compare with http://ideone.com/k2Tzb

Comment: Not sure what my finger is doing... It just happened.   Edited to take out the strtotime part

Comment: @zerkms what do you mean? I was pointing out the irony... never mind now, he fixed it. how was using `strtotime()` there correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong date format. Use this instead:

```
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));
```

Also, just compare the date, rather than the time:

```
SELECT SUM(amount), 
       SUM(amtnaira) 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  transtype = 'buy' 
       AND batch != '' 
       AND DATE(date) = $yesterday
```